# how to traverse only certain areas of a site? Basically stay within certain pages?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm using scrapy/spyder to build my crawler, using BeautifulSoup as well.. I have been working on a crawler and believe we are at a point that it works as expected with the few individual pages we have scraped, so my next challenge is to scrape the same site, but ONLY pages that are specific to a high level category.

Only thing i have tried is using allowed_domain and start_urls, but when i did that, it was literally hitting every page it was finding and we want to control what pages we scrape so we have a clean list of information.

I understand that on each page there are links that take you outside of the page you are and can end up elsewhere on the site.. but what im trying to do is only focus on a few pages within each category

```
#    allowed_domain = ['dickssportinggoods.com']
#    start_urls = ['https://www.dickssportinggoods.com/c/mens-top-trends-gear']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either base your spider on [Spider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy-spider) class and code the navigation yourself, or base it on the [CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) class and use the rules to control which pages get visited. From the information you provided it seems that the later approach is more appropriate for your requirement. Check out the [example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) to see how the rules work.